# how much of a process's memory is actively used?

Tags: linux, memory-usage

I've got a process that locks several gigs of memory using `mlock()`. Is there a way to tell how much of that memory is "actively" used versus how much, say, has not been accessed in the past x number of minutes?

Comment: Presumably all that it has locked otherwise why would it lock it.

Comment: If you have access to the /proc file system then there are plenty of information there. The first place I would look is /proc/$pid/smaps. Read about proportional set size (PSS) and Unique set size (USS).

Comment: @user430214 wrong presumption. Linux isn't the thing that's locking it. The user code is. Often people will mlockall() their whole memory space out of laziness, thinking that they'll gain better performance, even though a lot of it remains unused.

Comment: No, this is exactly the presumption I was making. The author decides what's required and erm that's it.

Comment: @user430214 That doesn't answer the question.